# Не отображается osm карта при использовании osmdroid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, openstreetmap

Нужна помощь с Osmdroid. Пытаюсь вывезти карту во фрагменте, используя свой тайловый сервис. Сервер 100% работает, но карта не выводится - серая сетка. Я новичок в этом деле, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?
Код fragemnt.kt:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_osm, container, false)
        val myOpenMapView = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.map) as MapView

        val tileSource: ITileSource = XYTileSource(
            "MyOSM", 1, 20, 256, ".png", arrayOf(
                "https://osm.site.com/osm/",
                "https://osm.site.com/osm/",
                "https://osm.site.com/osm/"
            ), "© OpenStreetMap contributors"
        )
        myOpenMapView.setUseDataConnection(true)
        myOpenMapView.setTileSource(tileSource)
        val mapController: IMapController = myOpenMapView.controller
        mapController.setZoom(14.5)
        val startPoint = GeoPoint(47.584072, 12.173591)
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint)
        return v
    }
```

Код Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить:

```
Configuration.getInstance().load(
        context,
        androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    )
```